# Evaluate the limit $a_{n+1}=\lambda a_n^2(1-a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $0<\lambda<4$ and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers satisfying $a_{n+1}=\lambda a_n^2(1-a_n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.How can I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and find this limit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since $a_n's$ have to be positive, each $a_n$ must lie between $0$ and $1$.

Now $a_{n+1}/a_n=\lambda a_n(1-a_n)$. Since $0< a_n < 1$, $a_n(1-a_n) \leq 4.$ So,

$a_{n+1}/a_n \leq \lambda /4 \leq 1.$ Hence $a_n's$ form a decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$. Hence, they must converge to some value, say $a$.

Note that $a$ must satisfy $a=\lambda a^2(1-a)$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 3):

We know that $a_{n} < 1$ for each $n$, or else $a_{n+1}$ would not be positive.  Since $a_{n}\in(0,1)$, we have $a_{n+1}/a_{n} = \lambda a_{n}(1-a_{n}) \in (0,1)$ as well, and more precisely $a_{n+1}/a_{n} \le \lambda/4 < 1$.  Since $a_{n}/a_{0} \le (\lambda/4)^{n}\rightarrow 0$, the sequence must converge to zero.